# How can I trap a particular value of the counter in the for loop

Tags: java

How can I trap a particular value of the counter in the for loop, for which I get the maximum calculated value ..for example:

```
import com.imonPhysics.projectile2;

public class motion2{

public static void main(String[] args){

    double range=0,v=35,maxrange=0,angle=0;
    int x=0;
    projectile2 p1=new projectile2();
    System.out.println("the given velocity is:  20  m/s \n" );
    System.out.println("The value of g is: 9.8 m/s^2\n\n" );

    for(int j=0;j<=90;j+=5){
      x=j;
      range=p1.calculate(v,j);
      System.out.println("For the angle :" + j+" the range is: " + range);
      if(range > maxrange)maxrange=range;

    }    

    System.out.println(" the maximum range is :"+ maxrange);
    System.out.println(" the angle at which the range is max is :   " + angle);


}

}
```

how can I trap the angle for maxrange.

Comment: Please elaborate more, we need some more information. Please indent your code to become more readable

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use exactly the same approach you are using to determine `maxrange`:

```
for (...) {
    ...

    if (range > maxrange) {
        maxrange = range;
        angle = j;  // <--
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand the problem correctly, but do you if you want the angle with that the max range is reached, then just do `angle = j` inside the if.

Comment: Don't forget that if you realize after posting that another answer (that's better or the same) has already been posted, there's no cost to deleting your post in order to avoid cluttering questions with answers that don't add anything.